# Is MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew(...) guaranteed to create a file with zeroes?

Tags: c#, zero, memory-mapped-files

As the title says; Can I rely on MemoryMappedFile to always create a file full of zeroes? I've tested by reading some newly created files but this "testing" seems futile, altough I have yet to see a non-zero byte.

Is there any documentation on this that I have missed, or is it simply a given that memory mapped files are empty on creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not guaranteed. This appears to be implementation-specific.

While not mentioned in `MemoryMappedFile`, the behavior of the underlying native API that it uses in .NET proper (`CreateFileMapping`) does explicitly document this, and it differs depending on the source of the storage.

In the case of a file-backed mapping:

> If the file is extended, the contents of the file between the old end
>   of the file and the new end of the file are not guaranteed to be zero;
>   the behavior is defined by the file system.

And in the case of an anonymous mapping (backed by page file):

> The initial contents of the pages in a file mapping object backed by
>   the operating system paging file are 0 (zero).

Comment: Do you have a source link, I'd like to look closer at the specifics.

Comment: Microsoft cannot make any promises about the file system, it is not in their control.  However, there isn't any in common use that doesn't generate zeros.